# How to print arrays with square brackets instead of curly brackets in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, json, curly-braces, square-bracket

I have this piece of code in my laravel controller and it prints an array as below: Iitems is a collection.

```
$i = [];
foreach($items as $item) {
    $i['grid'][$item->color]['color'] = $item->color;
    $item_list['grid'][$item->color]['size_grid'][$item->size_no] = [
                    'size_no' => $item->size_no,
                    'size_description' => $item->size_desc,
                    'on_hand' => $item->on_hand,
   ];
}
```

**Output:**

```
"grid": {
          "VELBL": {
            "color": "VELBL",
            "size_grid": {
              "3": {
                "size_no": 3,
                "size_description": "MEDIUM",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "5": {
                "size_no": 5,
                "size_description": "X LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "4": {
                "size_no": 4,
                "size_description": "LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "1": {
                "size_no": 1,
                "size_description": "X SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "2": {
                "size_no": 2,
                "size_description": "SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              }
            }
          },
          "BLUAS": {
            "color": "BLUAS",
            "size_grid": {
              "3": {
                "size_no": 3,
                "size_description": "MEDIUM",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "1": {
                "size_no": 1,
                "size_description": "X SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "2": {
                "size_no": 2,
                "size_description": "SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "4": {
                "size_no": 4,
                "size_description": "LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "5": {
                "size_no": 5,
                "size_description": "X LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              }
            }
          },
          "MHGR": {
            "color": "MHGR",
            "size_grid": {
              "1": {
                "size_no": 1,
                "size_description": "X SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "2": {
                "size_no": 2,
                "size_description": "SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "3": {
                "size_no": 3,
                "size_description": "MEDIUM",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "4": {
                "size_no": 4,
                "size_description": "LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "5": {
                "size_no": 5,
                "size_description": "X LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

This prints the result with curly brackets, but I need this to be print with square brackets. How can I achieve this? If I change my code it's not printing all necessary data, how can I print this same set of data with square brackets as below:

**Expected output:**

```
"grid": [
          "VELBL": {
            "color": "VELBL",
            "size_grid": [
              "3": {
                "size_no": 3,
                "size_description": "MEDIUM",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "5": {
                "size_no": 5,
                "size_description": "X LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "4": {
                "size_no": 4,
                "size_description": "LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "1": {
                "size_no": 1,
                "size_description": "X SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "2": {
                "size_no": 2,
                "size_description": "SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              }
            ]
          },
          "BLUAS": {
            "color": "BLUAS",
            "size_grid": [
              "3": {
                "size_no": 3,
                "size_description": "MEDIUM",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "1": {
                "size_no": 1,
                "size_description": "X SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "2": {
                "size_no": 2,
                "size_description": "SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "4": {
                "size_no": 4,
                "size_description": "LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "5": {
                "size_no": 5,
                "size_description": "X LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              }
            ]
          },
          "MHGR": {
            "color": "MHGR",
            "size_grid": [
              "1": {
                "size_no": 1,
                "size_description": "X SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "2": {
                "size_no": 2,
                "size_description": "SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "3": {
                "size_no": 3,
                "size_description": "MEDIUM",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "4": {
                "size_no": 4,
                "size_description": "LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "5": {
                "size_no": 5,
                "size_description": "X LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
```

Please, someone, help me here as am new to the technology. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
By adding this line of code, now this prints the grid array with square brackets, but the array inside it, size_grid not with square brackets, how can I print size_grid array also with square brackets?

```
$item_list['grid'] = array_values($item_list['grid']);
```

**Output:**

```
"grid": [
          {
            "color": "VELBL",
            "size_grid": {
              "3": {
                "size_no": 3,
                "size_description": "MEDIUM",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "5": {
                "size_no": 5,
                "size_description": "X LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "4": {
                "size_no": 4,
                "size_description": "LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "1": {
                "size_no": 1,
                "size_description": "X SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "2": {
                "size_no": 2,
                "size_description": "SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "color": "BLUAS",
            "size_grid": {
              "3": {
                "size_no": 3,
                "size_description": "MEDIUM",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "1": {
                "size_no": 1,
                "size_description": "X SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "2": {
                "size_no": 2,
                "size_description": "SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "4": {
                "size_no": 4,
                "size_description": "LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "5": {
                "size_no": 5,
                "size_description": "X LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "color": "MHGR",
            "size_grid": {
              "1": {
                "size_no": 1,
                "size_description": "X SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "2": {
                "size_no": 2,
                "size_description": "SMALL",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "3": {
                "size_no": 3,
                "size_description": "MEDIUM",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "4": {
                "size_no": 4,
                "size_description": "LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              },
              "5": {
                "size_no": 5,
                "size_description": "X LARGE",
                "on_hand": "0"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
```

Comment: how your checking .? output if your using `retrun` then by default laravel convert this to json so try with `dd()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To obtain a square bracketed result within grid, the simple solution would be something like this:

```php
// your existing code
$i = [];
foreach($items as $item) {
    $i['grid'][$item->color]['color'] = $item->color;
    $item_list['grid'][$item->color]['size_grid'][$item->size_no] = [
                    'size_no' => $item->size_no,
                    'size_description' => $item->size_desc,
                    'on_hand' => $item->on_hand,
   ];
}

// https://www.php.net/array_values
$item_list['grid'] = array_values($item_list['grid']);
```

**Update**: if you want size_grid to be numeric as well, you can do the following:

```php
// your existing code
foreach($items as $item) {
    ...
    // this line is updated, removal of "$item->size_no"
    $item_list['grid'][$item->color]['size_grid'][] = [
                    'size_no' => $item->size_no,
                    'size_description' => $item->size_desc,
                    'on_hand' => $item->on_hand,
   ];
}

// https://www.php.net/array_values
$item_list['grid'] = array_values($item_list['grid']);
```

**OR**

```
...

// https://www.php.net/array_values
$item_list['grid'] = array_values($item_list['grid']);

$item_list['grid'] = array_map(
  function ($item) { 
    $item['size_grid'] = array_values($item['size_grid']);
    return $item;
  }, 
  $item_list['grid']
);
```

Comment: thank you very much for this answer, but this not printing square brackets for the size_grid array :/

Comment: I've updated my question, please be kind enough to check it. thank you.